# Can't install Grails in Windows 8 using Cygwin

Tags: grails, cygwin

I'm having some problems installing Grails in Windows.

I'm using `gvm install grails`, and after downloading the files, it always show

```
Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.
```

I tried several times with the same result. Just to check, I tried in a laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 and I didn't have any problem at all.

Do you have any clue? Or if you know how can I get more information about the error, it would be also very helpful.

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Grails installation on Windows is very straight forward. Download the zip file and open it in a folder and add `GRAILS_HOME/bin` to Windows environment `PATH` variable.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. I'll try that way if I can't install gvm  today. I'd prefer to have a manager which can handle the different versions and so on.